# Cyclical dependencies installing gplots, gdata and gtools in R 3.0.2

Tags: linux, r, macos, installation, gplots

I am running R 3.0.2 and trying to install `gplots` on Mac OSX 10.9, CentOS 6.4 and 5.4. But it fails on all platforms. The main reason should be that `gdata` requires `gtools` and `gtools` requires `gdata`.

So if one tries to install `gtools` or `gdata` alone, it stops you by

```
> install.packages("gtools")
also installing the dependency ‘gdata’
...
ERROR: dependency ‘gtools’ is not available for package ‘gdata’
ERROR: dependency ‘gdata’ is not available for package ‘gtools’
```

However, based on [CRAN package info](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gdata/index.html), the dependency tree should be

```
gplots --> gdata --> gtools
A --> B: A depends on B
```

So is there any workaround or should this be reported upstream?

#### EDIT:

I managed to install them by modifying `gtools`'s source code:

```
> download.packages("gtools", destdir=".")  # currently 3.2.0
```

untar it (`tar zxf ./gtools_3.2.0.tar.gz`) then remove the line in file `DESCRIPTION`

```
# in gtools/DESCRIPTION
Imports: gdata  # <-- remove this line
```

Then install `gtools` locally

```
> install.packages("gtools", repos=NULL)
...
file ‘DESCRIPTION’ has the wrong MD5 checksum
...
```

It should be successfully installed thus the cyclical dependency is resolved. One can finish all the rest by

```
> install.packages("gplots")
```

This solution is originally given by Wush Wu.

Comment: You seem to be mistaken. `gtools` doesn't depend on anything as far as I can see.

Comment: It should not depend on `gdata` but currently this dependency is in its `DESCRIPTION`.

Comment: If anyone can reproduce this, then submit a bug report to the maintainer of `gtools`.  I cannot, on R 3.0.2, Win64, gtools3.2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the maintainer of gtools.

There is, indeed, a cyclic dependency in gtools 3.2.0, which I pushed to CRAN on Saturday.

CRAN has rolled gtools back to 3.1.1 (which preceded the problem) and I've just submitted gtools 3.2.1 to CRAN (which corrects the problem).

-Greg

Comment: UPDATE: gtools 3.2.1 is now available on CRAN.